# How to make mesh follow the shape of the ground plane

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

How can I place this stone wall so that it would take the shape of the ground plane but would still look like a wall that goes around the house? Using shrinkwrap modifier makes the mesh flat for some reason.

[image]

Comment: How did you make this mesh? Did you use a curve? Is the wall's bottom surface flat, before your desired deformation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bake Displacement from terrane and apply **Displace Modifier** on your wall.

1. Bake Displacement by set up shader to present highest and lowest point, black as lowest and white as highest. You can **Greater/Lesser Than** in **Math** node to find highest-lowest point then use that value in **Map Range** node in Min/Max. Then bake as Emit.
   [image: Baking Displacement]
   *Find highest point with Math node (left). Ready to bake (right). Image after bake (top-right)*
2. Create new **UVMap** for use with **Displace Modifier**. Unwarp your model from top (<kbd>numpad7</kbd>) select **Project from View**. Then create
   new Shader with this UVmap and image from baking, align UVmap to match with terrane on back.
   [image: Unwarp UVMap and align to match background]
   *Align UVmap to match black/white on terrane (left). Unwarp from top view (right).*

3.Add **Displace Modifier** to your model with these setting

- Coordinates: UV
- UV Map: UVMap(from 2.)
- Direction : Z

Then move your model to sit tight with terrane, adjust Strength in **Displace Modifier** to match surface. Use **Solidify** or **Smooth** modifier if it look messy.
[image: Apply Displace Modifier on torus]
*A torus from bottom (top-left). Place a torus on terrane(left).*

PS. If you need more detail about baking Displacement check out this video from [Default Cube](https://youtu.be/arvhK4tvYuY).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply!

Answer (score 1):

two ways to do that

1.if it's lowpoly.
then copy the cycle line of the bottom(as Cyc),duplicate and seperate it,change a little shape of Cyc as you wish to make it looks real.
Cyc use shrinkwrap to the ground.
linebridge Cyc and the buttom cycle of the wall.

2.if it has many many vertice,I mean it contains many different rocks.
make a bottom cycle box of the wall,add particleSystem.
creat some rocks by Rock Generator,and add the rocks to the particleSystem.